# Delete function for MySQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

this is so that I will have to build a delete function, I try to google it but no luck was with me. then could not find a good function or whatever you call it.

this is so that I will have to delete a user

Hope you / i can help me further

It is the first time that I have to use the delete function in MySQLI to my website. :)

hope you can give me some information.

Comment: [`DELETE FROM tablename WHERE somecol = 'someval'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: You can't find anything related using a modern search engine and the terms "delete+mysql"? I won't believe that…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am guessing you want to delete user from you mysql table, if yes then you can write a query using mysql `DELETE` keyword

```
"DELETE FROM `your-tbale(i.e users)` where `columnName` = 'somevalue'"
```

hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: "DELETE FROM `brugere` where `id` = '$_SESSION["user_id"]'"

Comment: yeah you got it, and make sure you passed escaped data to your queries to avoid sql injections.

Comment: yes :) How to do it like I do here with the updater

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `brugere` SET `password`=? WHERE `id`=?'))
    { 
       $stmt->bind_param('si', $password, $id);

       $password = sha1($_POST['password']); 
       $id = $_SESSION["user_id"];

       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->close();

Comment: i think you might want to look into the follwing post

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145520/mysqli-update-query-issue]

Comment: sorry but it make me confused to get anything as I have no need for all .. :) I just need it quick and enkeldt if you can put it like that.

Comment: i am not getting u dear, ur question `title` says that u want to delete something, ur above comment says that you want to update something, what exactly u want ? and there is no mysql Delete or update function, its wot u have to use in this way( i guess i am not wrong ), so what it is it that you actually trying to do ?

Comment: i still can edit my answer according to your need, so try to be specific dear

Comment: Okay. hope it's okay with you :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you only need to run the query:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

However it seems that you find "special problems" with that, probably this post will give you a hint:

[Mysqli DELETE QUERY not working in PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153255/mysqli-delete-query-not-working-in-php-script)